# maven remembers deleted repos

Tags: maven, download, repository, artifact

I had some repo in my project's main module' pom.xml file which maven couldn't download any library (artifact) from. I made a decision to remove that repo from pom.xml and use another one. When I run command : **mvn clean install**   - it print out that it is trying to download libraries from that first bloody ( already deleted from project configuration {pom.xml file} ) repository ....

How to make maven forget about deleted and even not mentioned in project repositories ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For example, my maven project being build tries to download an artifact from http://repo.aduno-software.org ( which is completely unavailable for months ) while there is NO ANY explicit note about it in pom.xml files as well as in settings.xml.... How Maven knows from where to download a dependency ? And how to make it change its decision ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be that this repository is also mentionned in your maven settings. This file is by default in `.m2/settings.xml` in your personal directory.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but there is no any setting.xml file in .m2 directory, and this repository ( which I try making maven to forget about ) is not mentioned even in %MAVEN_HOME%/conf/settings.xml file....